# Mongoose select query between two time range

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Ok this is getting interesting, im working on a school project schedule, and use mongoDB,
which has no time attribute.

I want to query between two time ranges in a class.

> This SQL Query works but im trying this in mongoose:

```
SELECT * From Schedule WHERE room_name = ?  AND ((start_time) BETWEEN @KP and @KD OR (end_time) BETWEEN @KP and @KD)  AND day=?
```

For example:

> First lecture starts from 08:00 till 09:00 in room number 8 on Monday.
>
> If i try to add another lecture with start time: 08:30 end time: 09:30 in room number 8 on Monday , it should tell me that i can not because the class is busy at the moment.

This is the Schema im using:

```
    day: Number,
    start_time: Date,
    end_time: Date,
    room: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' }]
```

I need ideas how can i solve this :) because im a begginer in mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the model name is Lecture.

```
var newStartTime; //Start time for class to be created.
var newEndTime;   //End time for class to be created.

Lecture.find({$and: [
{$or: [{$and: [{start_time: {$lte: newStartTime}}, {end_time: {$gte: newStartTime}}]}, {$and: [{start_time: {$lte: newEndTime}}, {end_time: {$gte: newEndTime}}]}]},
{$not: {$or: [{start_time: {$eq: newEndTime}}, {end_time: {$eq: newStartTime}}]}}
]}, function (err, results) {

    if (err) {
        //handle error
        return;
    }

    if (results.length > 0)
    {
        //Clashing class, handle
    }
});
```

The above query checks for lectures that:

Comment: this worked perfect, but in this query u have missed a bracket.
Thanks in response ut the man :)

Comment: im using this query and it works perfectly , but when i have a schedule that starts from: 10.00 ends to 11.00, and i want to insert another one that starts from 11.00 to 12.00 it doesnt accept i must enter
11.01 - 12.00.
I removed the equals at the query but than the query wont work properly

Comment: p.s i save the startTime and endTime in schema as String, cause it didnt accept it as Date format.

Comment: That will be an issue.. It would be better if you store them in 24 hour number format: eg. 0 -> 12 AM, 1130 -> 11:30 AM, 1330 -> 1:30 PM

Comment: so u say , i should store them in AM PM format , but than will i be albe to substract one minute from them in the query im using ?

Comment: i checked it still doenst work, but i havend managed to store the time in 12 AM PM format, cause it doenst accept only time it must be a date in mongoDB.

this is the excact query im using:
http://pastebin.com/SCrgX6QT

Comment: I'm not saying that you store the times in AM PM format, but in 24 hour format as numbers, where 0 represents 12AM, 1100 represents 11AM, 1300 represents 1PM and so on

Comment: yeah good idea i stored them as numbers for exampe 08:00 is 0800 (in db is saved as 800) , but still the query doesnt work when i try to add a schedule that starts from 0700 till 0800, cause there already exists a record which start from 0800, when i try start time 0700 end time: 0759 it works.

Comment: this was perfect , u just didnt catch one case: 
we have 10:00 - 12:00, user can add this 09:00 - 13:00.
thanks to you i think i solved it , im just going to test it now , to check if there are any issues.
I will post an answer bottom with the fixed query.
Again thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ZeMoon i solved my problem, here is the full query if someone needs it:

```
$or: [{$and: [
                {$or: [
                        {$and: [{start_time: {$lt: newStartTime}}, {end_time: {$gt: newStartTime}}]}, 
                        {$and: [{start_time: {$lt: newEndTime}}, {end_time: {$gt: newEndTime}}]},
                        {$and: [{start_time: {$gte: newStartTime}}, {end_time: {$lte: newEndTime}}]},

            ]},
                        {$or: [{start_time: {$ne: newStartTime}}, {end_time: {$ne: newEndTime}}]},

                 ]
                    },
                        {$and: [{start_time: {$eq: newStartTime}}, {end_time: {$eq: newEndTime}}]}
            ]
```

Comment: @ZeMoon yeah i hope so thanks a lot, even that i didnt understand exactly what did u query there xD , its too complicated for me , mby someday when u have time u can explain me the query.
Thanks again, u helped me a lot with this :)